# Conversions from Unsigned Integral Types style. Is this style good?

Tags: c++, c

Many times I see programmers doing the following cast

```
unsigned long long minimumValue;
minimumValue = (unsigned long long)-1;
```

but why do they do this, rather than `int minimumValue = -1`?

Comment: `minimumValue` is a misleading name. This gives the **maximum** value of an unsigned type.

Comment: @MikeSeymour But when I do

   `unsigned long long value = (unsigned long long) -1;`
     `printf("%lld", value);` It return me `-1`

Comment: `"%lld"` is not for `unsigned long long`. you should use `%llu`

Comment: @Anatoly that is because the format specifier `%lld` is printing a signed value.

Comment: `%lld` specifies that it should be treated as a signed `long long`, giving undefined since it isn't a valid value for that type. Try `%llu`, or `cout << value` in C++.

Comment: I remember when I was a junior developer looking at line that was something like `unsigned long long i = ~0ull;` for a long time before I figured out what they were doing... then you get used to a pattern and can read them interchangeably... the reason to go to your largest int size is so that sign extension doesn't become an issue and mess up your comparisons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a trick to give the maximum (not minimum) value of an unsigned type. Conversion from a signed value uses modular arithmetic to give a value in the range of the unsigned type; so `-1` becomes `pow(2,N)-1` for an unsigned type with `N` bits, which is the largest representable value.

The cast isn't strictly necessary, but some compilers might give a warning without it.

A better style might be to specify `ULLONG_MAX`, or `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max()` in C++.

Comment: I was going to post an answer: *`-1` is by default a signed `int`. So if you want to assign that value to `unsigned long long` the cast is needed to be clear as to your intention*. But yours is better.

Comment: What about `std::numeric_limits<decltype(minimumValue)>::max()`? Though I'd go the other way around, and write `auto minimumValue = …;`